# Older records of ship movements

Tags: ship

Trying to reconstruct the Navy travels of myself, my father, my uncle, and my father-in-law.

Is there an online source for location information of U.S. Navy ships 1975-1987 ?  Or merchant marine?

Old enough to no longer be classified, but so far, no response to a NARA or Navy FOIA request.

NARA has ships logs, but they haven't responded to any messages about it.

Navy has [MOVREPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movement_Report_System) since 1945, and I sent an inquiry to the FOIA office (not an official request) that has not yet been answered.

http://hullnumber.com has what looks like movement details, but they're provided by people who were on the ship.  Most of the ones that interest me aren't there, and some that are there I know are wrong.

I discovered a site that claims I have direct online access to my own military record, but the web forms to create an account are broken.  (And that won't help me access records of deceased relatives.)

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Your question could be improved by adding more information about your research effort.  "No response from NARA or Navy" tells us nothing about how you tried to make contact with them. Also, websites might exist showing the history of indivudual ships, but you haven't told us if you've searched for the information you wanted.

Comment: I clarified "No response from NARA or Navy" and then noticed I had already done so in the next two paragraphs.